# simple regex -- replace underscore with a space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

Hey, I'm writing my first Rails app, and I'm trying to replace the underscores form an incoming id name with spaces, like this:

**before**: test_string

**after**:  test string

How can I do this? Sorry if this is a bit of a dumb question, I'm not very familiar with regular expressions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whoops, I actually had it working--just forgot to update the variable name :P

I was using this:

```
@id = params[:id]
@title = @id.gsub("_", " ")
```

Answer (score 36):

```
str.gsub!(/_/, ' ')
```

`gsub` stands for 'global substitution', and the exclamation means it'll change the string itself rather than just return the substituted string.

You can also do it without regexes using `String#tr!`:

```
str.tr!('_', ' ')
```

Comment: `str.tr!('_', ' ')` will return nil if `str` doesn't include any `_`

Answer (score 32):

On rails you can use the simplier [`.humanize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) and ruby's [`.downcase`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-downcase) method but be careful as it also strips any final '_id' string (in most cases this is just what you need, even the capitalized first letter)

```
'text_string_id'.humanize.downcase
 => "text string"
```

Comment: Alternatively, `'text_string_id'.humanize(capitalize: false)` will allow you to skip the extra `downcase` transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Using split and join in rails

"test_string".split('_').join(' ')

Comment: Not only in rails. split() and join() are standard ruby methods.